# Array Manipulation on Hackerrank

Tags: arrays, testcasesource

What is the issue with my code? It only passes 6 of my testcases and I am sure I am making some mistake but I am not able to figure it out. Also if someone could help me understand the space and time complexity of this code I would be more than grateful. Thank You.

```
def arrayManipulation(n, queries):
    arr = [0]*(n+2)
    for q in queries:
        print(q)
        a = q[0]
        b = q[1]
        k = q[-1]
        arr[a] += k
        arr[b+1] -= k
        print(arr)
      
    max_sum = temp =  0
    for i in arr:
        print(i)
        temp += i
        print("TEMP:",temp)
        max_sum = max(max_sum,temp)
        print("MAXSUM:",max_sum)
    return max_sum
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')
    nm = input().split()
    n = int(nm[0])
    m = int(nm[1])
    queries = []
    for _ in range(m):
        queries.append(list(map(int, input().rstrip().split())))
    result = arrayManipulation(n, queries)
    fptr.write(str(result) + '\n')
    fptr.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is within following part of your code:

```
    max_sum = temp =  0
for i in arr:
    print(i)
    temp += i
    print("TEMP:",temp)
    max_sum = max(max_sum,temp)
    print("MAXSUM:",max_sum)
return max_sum
```

max_sum and temp are both integer type which can only handle number up to 2147483647 before overflow. But the question specify that k is within range of 0 to 10^9, when those number adds up it will easily overflow. Try to use long instead of int.